# Newbie Javascript issue - ReferenceError: object is not defined

Tags: javascript

Ful disclosure - I'm a Javascript newbie and have just enrolled in a coding bootcamp.  As part of our training the following issue came up for me, which is probably simple, but I'm still getting an error.

Here is my code thus far, per the instructions:

In properties.js:

```
function setPropertiesOnObjLiteral(obj) {
  obj.x = 7;
  obj.y = '8';
  obj.i = onePlus(obj.i);
}
```

In propertiesSpec.js:

```
var object  = {
  x: 3,
  y: '2',
  onePlus: function(i) {
    i = i+1;
  }
};

setPropertiesOnObjLiteral(object);
```

I am getting a host of errors here, saying that onePlus is not defined and similar.  I read online that when you pass an object as a function argument, then you are passing a reference and that any changes made in the function should affect the original object.  Also, I'm not sure if I should be using the prototype command here or not.

Thanks a lot.  Pointing me in the right direction here should solve my questions for the rest of the assignment!

Answer (score 0):

Function `onePlus` is not visible for method `setPropertiesOnObjLiteral`, it just doesn't exist for it. It belongs to `object`. Variables and methods have a valid scope, outside scope they can't be used.

Correct usage would be

```
obj.i = obj.onePlus(obj.i); // "onePlus" belongs to obj
```

You also need to return result from method to be used outside

```
onePlus: function(i) {
    return i+1;
}
```

To keep your `setPropertiesOnObjLiteral` code as it is, you have to move `onePlus`.

```
var object = {
  x: 3,
  y: '2'
};

function onePlus(i) {
    return i+1;
}
```